# How to mock user authentication on Rails with Pact contract verification?

Tags: pact, pact-ruby

On a Pact verification stage I need to mock user authentication. What is the best way to do it?
I'm using Rails 4 with Devise.

I found a very hacky looking solution, which works but looks ugly and I hope there's another way to do it.
I'm replacing the `app` inside of the Pact suite and manually setting user for `warden` if it's required. User ID is being set inside the provider state. It looks like this:

```
Pact.service_provider "Some Service Provider" do
  app { ProxyApp.new(Rails.application) }
  ...

class ProxyApp
  ...

  def call(env)
    # Mock user authentication
    env['warden'] ||= begin
      manager = Warden::Manager.new(nil) do |config|
        config.merge! Devise.warden_config
      end
      Warden::Proxy.new(env, manager)
    end
    user_id = EnvMock.get_user_id # user ID is being set inside the provider state
    env['warden'].set_user(Account.find(user_id), scope: :account) if user_id

    ...
  end
end
```

I really hope that there's some completely different perspective that allows to accomplish this task in much more beautiful way.

Comment: Using a proxy app is the way I would have approached it too. I don't know of a more elegant solution.

Comment: I do remember a conversation about using Warden from the pact-support group though - Andre created an example code base [here](https://github.com/allavena/sinatra-warden-example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I verify pacts against an API that requires an auth token?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777493/how-do-i-verify-pacts-against-an-api-that-requires-an-auth-token)