# Encoded / Encrypted body before verifying a Pact

Tags: pact, pact-ruby

A server I need to integrate with returns its answers encoded as a JWT. Worse, the response body actually is a json, of the form:

`{d: token}    with token = JWT.encode({id: 123, field: "John", etc.})`

I'd like to use a pact verification on the content of the decoded token. I know I can easily have a pact verifying that I get back a {d: string}, I can't do an exact match on the string (as the JWT contains some varying IDs). What I want is the following, which presumes the addition of a new Pact.JWT functionality.

`my_provider.
          upon_receiving('my request')
          .with(method: :post,
                path: '/order',
                headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
          ).will_respond_with(
          status: 200,
          headers: {'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
          body: {
              d: Pact::JWT( {
                               id: Pact.like(123),
                               field: Pact.term(generate: "John", matcher: /J.*/
              },signing_key,algo
              )
         })`

Short of adding this Pact::JWT, is there a way to achive this kind of result?

I am already using the pact proxy to run my verification. I know you can modify the request before sending it for verification ([How do I verify pacts against an API that requires an auth token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777493/how-do-i-verify-pacts-against-an-api-that-requires-an-auth-token)). Can you modify the request once you receive it from the proxy server?

If that's the case, I can plan for the following work around:

- a switch in my actual code to sometimes expect the answers decoded instead of in the JWT
- run my tests once with the swich off (normal code behaviour, mocks returns JWT data encoded.
- run my tests a second time with the swich off (code expect data already decoded, mocks return decoded data.)
- use the contract json from this second run
- hook into the proxy:verify task to decode the JWT on the fly, and use the existing pact mechanisms for verification.  (Step that I do not know how to do).

My code is in ruby. I do not have access to the provider.

Any suggestions appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the request or response by using (another) proxy app.

```
class ProxyApp

  def initialize real_provider_app
    @real_provider_app = real_provider_app
  end

  def call env
    response = @real_provider_app.call(env)
    # modify response here
    response
  end
end

Pact.service_provider "My Service Provider" do
  app { ProxyApp.new(RealApp) }
end
```

Comment: The Pact.service_provider goes into the provider code (if any), and needs a require 'pact/provider' 
For Rails, the app is defined in config/application, where you have module MyAppName   class Application,
you'll want MyAppName::Application

This answers it, though I'm not using it, rather, I've forked pact-support to add support for a Pact.Jwt object.

Answer (score 0):

Pact as a tool, I don't expect it to give this behavior out of the box.

In my opinion, the best is,

- Do not change source code only for tests
- Make sure your tests verifies encoded json only (generate encoded expected json in test & verify that with actual)